# Load json file in Django

Tags: jquery, json, django

Currently, I am using code below to load data.json file:

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.json", function(data) {
```

However, there is always an error like this:
"GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.json 404 (Not Found)".

File structures:

The data.json file is under the directory where my home.html locates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's `runserver` maps all URLs via the `urls.py` mechanism. If you want to serve a static file, you need to put that in your static files directory and use the STATIC_URL to point to that file (e.g. /static/data.json). See [the documentation on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/).

And specifically on how to serve static files in your development environment, here are the [instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)